# Can't solve errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to fix the error mentioned in the title with no luck. My data types and lengths are the same and I've also set the ENGINE and CHARSET.

Please take a look at my code. Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sa_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    address1 VARCHAR(70),
    address2 VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    suburb VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    province VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    zip INT(6) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    password CHAR(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Votes table:

```
CREATE TABLE votes (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sa_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    party VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    province VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (sa_id) REFERENCES users(sa_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Error: Can't create table 'savs_db'.'votes' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: [I get this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb4ba8a24a82ca60990c68d54c35fb4b): "Missing index for constraint 'votes_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'users'"

Comment: A foreign key must reference a key (e.g. the primary key.)

Comment: @jarlh actually the MySQL allows referencing non-key columns but they must be indexed.

Comment: @MichalHynčica I'll check this out and try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took @Michal Hynčica's advice and found the solution. I failed to index the non-key column I was referencing. I added `INDEX (sa_id)` to line 14.

Solution:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        sa_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        address1 VARCHAR(70),
        address2 VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
        suburb VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        province VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        zip INT(6) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
        password CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        INDEX (sa_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: That part `sa_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL REFERENCES users(sa_id),` is wrong. MySQL parses but ignores inline refereces definitions in column definitions. If it wasn't ignored it would cause an error because you are telling MySQL that `sa_id` column should reference itself. Having `INDEX (sa_id)` should be enough for other tables to be able to reference `sa_id` column.

Comment: @MichalHynčica alright, will remove the unnecessary code